# "indexOf" method of LinkedLIST not providing the expected output when you're using the for-loop

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;  
public class Main {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
 LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();  
  for (int i=100;i<=600;i+=100)  
  {  
   l1.add(i);  
  }  
  System.out.println(l1);  
  System.out.println(l1.indexOf("200"));  
  System.out.println(l1.lastIndexOf("200"));  
 }  
}
```

output:
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]

> -1   ***<-------------why are you getting this o/p...cant we use for-loop to add datas sequentially in ascending order of indexes ***

-1

---

```
LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();  
l1.add("100");  
l1.add("200");  
l1.add("300");  
l1.add("400");  
  System.out.println(l1);  
  System.out.println(l1.indexOf("200"));  
  System.out.println(l1.lastIndexOf("200"));  
 }
```

output:
[100, 200, 300, 400]

> 1  ***<-------------------while adding individually you're getting the right o/p; I mean the way I have expected***

1

---

```
LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();  
for (int i=100;i<=600;i+=100)  
 {  
  l1.add(i);  
 }  
l1.add("100");  
l1.add("200");  
l1.add("300");  
l1.add("400");  
 System.out.println(l1);  
 System.out.println(l1.indexOf("200"));  
 System.out.println(l1.lastIndexOf("200"));
```

output:
[100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 100, 200, 300, 400]

> 7   ***<---this o/p doesnt even care about the elements added using for loop..only the elements added individually are taken into account..why so***

7

Comment: I don't see any unexpected output ! 200 is not "200", one is an Integer and the other a String.

Comment: In the first case you're adding integer values in LinkedList and searching indexof String "200", while in second case you're adding String values in the LinkedList and thus its finds value "200"

Answer (score 1):

You are adding int to the list but trying to get String's index. You can try this,

```
System.out.println(l1.indexOf(200));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an integer (`int i`). This **might** be the problem. Try converting to a string when you add the values. For example:

```
import java.util.*;  
public class Main {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
 LinkedList l1=new LinkedList();  
  for (int i=100;i<=600;i+=100)  
  {  
   l1.add(String.valueOf(i));  
  }  
  System.out.println(l1);  
  System.out.println(l1.indexOf("200"));  
  System.out.println(l1.lastIndexOf("200"));  
 }  
}
```

Comment: I just compiled using `String.valueOf(i)`, and it worked properly.